# Recommend a tool for managing bak files?

Tags: server, bash, backup, mssql

I have an ubuntu-server running MS SQL Server Express and a bash script running backups of the databases every 24 hours.

I could spend a lot of time scripting something to manage the files, but if there's a tool out there that it can do it for me, even better.

Ideally I'd like to keep hold of:

- the last 14 days
- *Nth* day of every month for the past six months

Can anyone make a recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt the is something like that.

> I have an ubuntu-server running MS SQL Server Express and a bash script running backups of the databases every 24 hours.

I would add the backup on the nth day here too. Store the backups with a timetamp in a map ./daily/ and on the nth day store that backup also in a ./month/ map.

You get a couple of extra features: you can verify the monthly backup is there. You can restore it into a different server to verify it can be restored. And the delete is less complicated.

Delete after 14 days:

```
find ./daily/* -mtime +14 -exec rm {} \;
```